# Segmentation fault in int matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault

I was experimenting some basic C code that defines an `int` matrix with pointers.

```
typedef int **Matrix;

Matrix createMatrix(int lines, int columns) {
    int i, j;
    Matrix m = (Matrix) malloc(sizeof(int) * lines * columns);
    for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    Matrix m = createMatrix(5, 10);
    // ...
    if (m[2][3] == 20) {
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, these `m[i][j]` accesses are throwing segmentation faults. What's wrong here? Too many asterisks?

I was convinced that a pointer to a pointer to an int was effectively the same as a matrix.

Comment: did you include `stdlib.h`?

Comment: check some other questions on "how to allocate a 2-d array" on this site, there are many working examples

Comment: Do you know the difference between an array and a pointer? A pointer to a pointer, an array of pointers, and an array of arrays are completely different things (although the second one can be pointed to with the first one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your allocation of the `Matrix` data item assumes you're accessing it linearly with a single index. If you want to access it with two indices, *e.g.*, `m[1][1]` you need to allocate each dimension:

```
Matrix m = malloc(sizeof(int *) * lines);

for ( int i = 0; i < lines; i++ )
    m[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
```

Note also that you [should not type cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Silly mistake. It makes sense to allocate each of the arrays individually.

Comment: @afsantos it is actually common when someone first learns to allocate a multidimensional array. The way to look a it is `m[i][j]` is indexing `i` off of the `m` address, and indexing `j` off of the `m[i]` address.